# Best way to render a map in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, maps

I am new to groovy and grails, hence this simple doubt. I have a map like this: [0:[A,B,C,D], 1:[a,b,c,d]]. I want to display it as follows: 
 A: a
B:b
C:c
D:d 
 How do you display the data column wise? The .gsp I have now is shown below and all it does is display the values row wise.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <title>Parsed Map</title>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <table>
            <g:each in="${myMap}" var="element">
                <tr>
                    <g:each in="${element.value }" >
                            <th>${it}</th>
                         </g:each>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
        </table>                
    </body>
</html>
```

Pointing me in right direction for understanding maps in groovy will also be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Refer [Groovy Maps](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps) for use cases/examples and [API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html) for available methods on map. Hope that helps. Give a shout if you need more information. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have already validated that the columns and header lists have the same number of elements, you could do something like this...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <title>Parsed Map</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <g:each var="heading" in="${headings}" status="counter">
                <tr>
                    <th>${heading}</th>
                    <td>${values[counter]}</td>
                </tr>
            </g:each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works with the same controller I described in another answer.

Comment: I have a working controller, all I needed was the display code. It helped ! Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I have to work a lot with tables too, can you point me to a resource where I can learn different ways of displaying the tables in gsp files?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your example is a simplified version of your real problem.  Depending on what you are really trying to do, you have a number of options.  A simple thing might be like this (organize the table however you like, but this should give you the idea...):

```
// grails-app/controllers/com/demo/DemoController.groovy
package com.demo

class DemoController {

    def index() {
        // presumably you got this Map from somewhere and it isn't hardcoded here
        def someMap = [0:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 1:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

        def headings = someMap[0]
        def values = someMap[1]

        [headings: headings, values: values]
    }
}


// grails-app/views/demo/index.gsp
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <title>Parsed Map</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <g:each var="heading" in="${headings}">
                <th>${heading}</th>
            </g:each>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <g:each var="value" in="${values}">
                <th>${value}</th>
            </g:each>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, yes you are right in assuming that it part of a bigger problem. But this one still doesn't solve it. I still get the output row wise. I want A:a, then B:b etc. This one gives me A B C D and then a b c d in the next line. Can you tell me how do I get this?